# Analyzing Collatz-like sequences

Tags: code-golf, math, number, sequence

We define a [Collatz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture)-like sequence `s` with 4 positive integers:

- `n` starting value
- `d > 1` divisor
- `m > 1` multiplier
- `i` increment

(In the original Collatz sequence `d = 2` `m = 3` and `i = 1`.)

Given these integers `s` will be created in the following manner:

- `s(0) = n`
- if `k > 0` and `s(k-1) mod d = 0` then `s(k) = s(k-1) / d`
- if `k > 0` and `s(k-1) mod d != 0` then `s(k) = s(k-1) * m + i`

An example sequence with `d = 2, m = 3, i = 5` and `n = 80` will be `s = 80, 40, 20, 10, 5, 20, 10, 5, 20, ...`.

Every sequence will either reach higher values than any given bound (i.e. the sequence is divergent) or get into an infinite loop if for some `t` and `u` (`t!=u`) the `s(t) = s(u)` equality will be true.

In our problem if the value of a sequence element is larger than `10^9` or there is no element repetition before the `1000`th element the sequence is considered divergent.

### The task

You should write a program or function which takes the positive integers `d` `m` and `i` as inputs and outputs all the different ending types of the sequences (infinite loops and divergence) which the starting values `n = 1, 2, 3, ... 999, 1000` can produce.

### Input details

- The input is a string or list (or closest equivalent in your language) representing (in the common way) three positive integers `d`, `m` and `i` in that order. `d` and `m` are at least `2`. Neither number is larger than `100`.

### Output details

*The output specification is a bit wordy. Might worth to check out the examples first.*

- You should output to the standard output (or closest alternative) or return a string.
- If divergent sequence is possible the first line should be `DIVERGENT`.
- A unique representation of a sequence's loop is it's rotation where the smallest number is the last separated by spaces. E.g. if `s = 2 1 4 2 1 4 2 1` the loop is `4 2 1`.
- In every following line you should output every unique loop exactly once preceded by the word `LOOP`. E.g. `LOOP 4 2 1`
- The loops should be in ascending order in regard of their last element.
- Trailing newline is optional.

### Examples:

The first lines are the inputs and the following ones until a blank line are the outputs.

```
2 3 1
LOOP 4 2 1

2 2 6
LOOP 8 4 2 1
LOOP 12 6 3

3 7 8
DIVERGENT
LOOP 15 5 43 309 103 729 243 81 27 9 3 1
LOOP 22 162 54 18 6 2
LOOP 36 12 4

3 9 1
DIVERGENT

6 9 9
DIVERGENT
LOOP 18 3 36 6 1
LOOP 27 252 42 7 72 12 2
LOOP 45 414 69 630 105 954 159 1440 240 40 369 3330 555 5004 834 139 1260 210 35 324 54 9 90 15 144 24 4
LOOP 81 738 123 1116 186 31 288 48 8
LOOP 99 900 150 25 234 39 360 60 10
LOOP 126 21 198 33 306 51 468 78 13

10 10 10
LOOP 20 2 30 3 40 4 50 5 60 6 70 7 80 8 90 9 100 10 1

93 91 92
DIVERGENT
LOOP 2185 198927 2139 23
LOOP 4278 46
```

[Reference implementation in Python 3 on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/OMl6aK)

This is code-golf so shortest entry wins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Python 3, <s>269</s> <s>254</s> <s>252</s> 246 bytes

```py
d,m,i=eval(input())
S=set()
for n in range(1,1001):
 T=X=()
 while len(T)**3<1e9>=n:
  T=(n,)+T;n=[n//d,n*m+i][n%d>0]
  if n in T:I=T.index;L=T[:I(n)+1];M=I(min(L));X=L[M:]+L[:M]
 S|={X}
for x in sorted(S):print(x and"LOOP"or"DIVERGENT",*x[::-1])
```

*(Now 10 times slower to save a few bytes. Typical code golf.)*

Input a list via STDIN (e.g. `[2, 3, 1]`). I'm thinking that there's got to be a better way of standardising the cycles...

The approach is quite straightforward — test all 1000 numbers and take only the unique outputs. However, there are two little tricks in there:

- Loops are represented by nonempty tuples, but more importantly divergence is represented by an *empty* tuple. This is good because:

  - It doesn't break `sorted`, and will even appear *before* all the loop tuples
  - It allows us to select a string via `x and"LOOP"or"DIVERGENT"`
  - `*()[::-1]` doesn't affect `print`
- The loops are built backwards to turn "sort ascending by last element" into "sort ascending by first element", which removes the need to pass a lambda into `sorted`.

### Previous submission, 252 bytes

```py
d,m,i=eval(input())
def f(n,T=()):
 x=[n//d,n*m+i][n%d>0];I=T.index
 if x in T:L=T[:I(x)+1];M=I(min(L));return L[M:]+L[:M]
 return()if(T[1000:]or x>1e9)else f(x,(x,)+T)
for x in sorted(set(map(f,range(1,1001)))):print(x and"LOOP"or"DIVERGENT",*x[::-1])
```

This one's a lot faster.